# Dell inspiron 1501 ubuntu 14.04 lts 32bit doesn't work but ethernet work

Tags: 14.04, networking, dell, ethernet, inspiron

I install ubuntu 14.04 on my old laptop but wifi doesn't work and when i use fn+f2 keys for wifi nothing change.
sometime when i boot xp and use wifi and boot ubuntu again wifi led still run but wifi doesnt work.

I can connect to net with ethernet cable 
I try some instruction in some  site but nothing change like:

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
 sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

please help me
sorry for my bad english.

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g   WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install firmware. Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: when i use this  and reboot nothing change but when i boot xp and then reboot ubuntu its work very good thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to do it when connected to internet.